# Commultiplication and antipode in Hopf algebra?

Tags: hopf-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hopf algebra with antipode $S$. For $h \in H$, we have $(S \otimes S) \circ \Delta(h) = \tau \circ \Delta \circ S(h)$, where $\tau(a \otimes b) = b \otimes a$ and $\Delta$ is the commultiplication. How to prove this identity? Thank you very much.

Comment: See proposition 4.0.1 4) of Hopf algebras by Sweedler and use that $\tau\circ \tau=Id$. Or see proposition 4.2.6 iii) of Hopf algebras by Dascalescu, Nastasescu and Raianu if you prefer modern writing. The proof of the property is a nice trick though.

Comment: @Mathematician42, thank you very much.