# Hopf algebra basic

Tags: abstract-algebra

In some books there are assertions, usually without proof,
that
$m \circ (S \otimes S) = S \circ m \circ\tau :  A^{\otimes 2} \rightarrow A$
and
$\tau \circ (S \otimes S)\circ \Delta = \Delta \circ S : A \rightarrow A^{\otimes 2}$
Where $\Delta$ coproduct, $\tau$ is switching morphism, $S$ is antipode,  $m$ is multiplication. It is said that it follows from Hopf algebra axioms. How..?

Comment: the first is the statement that S is an antihomomorphism, which you can find in any Hopf algebra source e.g. https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pBJ6sbPHA0IC&pg=PA153&dq=%22is+an+antimorphism+of+algebras%22&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22is%20an%20antimorphism%20of%20algebras%22&f=false

Comment: the second is a dupe of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878942/commultiplication-and-antipode-in-hopf-algebra

Comment: Proofs of both statements can be found in Kassel's *Quantum Groups* as Theorem III.3.4(a).